# Centering SKSpriteNode in landscape mode by programing. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a game that is only in landscape mode and I have an SKSpriteNode that I am trying to center it to middle of the screen no matter what size of device the person is using. I have tried many things but it does not seem to be working well.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show us what have you tried: there is so much ways to make it done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option which will place a node at the center of the screen (which will actually place the node at the center of the scene) is something like this:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .purpleColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))       
sprite.position =  CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y:frame.midY)      
addChild(sprite)
```

This will place your node at the center of the screen no matter how your scene is sized (if it is bigger than a view, or smaller) or what `scaleMode` you actually use.